# igraph axes xlim ylim plot incorrectly

Tags: r, plot, igraph

if I make a graph `g`:

```
g <- read.table(text="

 A  B   W

 1  55  3
 2  55  5
 3  99  6 ",header=TRUE)

library(igraph)
g <- graph.data.frame(g)
```

and  matrix of coordinates:

```
y<-1:5
x<-c(0.1,0.1,0.2,0.2,0.8)
l<-data.frame(x,y)
l<-as.matrix(l)
```

I can plot the graph with node positions according to custom coordinates and plot axes.

```
plot(g,layout=l,rescale=F,axes=TRUE,ylim=c(0,6),xlim=c(0,1))
```

[image: graph with wrong axes]

But the xaxis limits do not function properly and I think are altered by yaxis limits.  How can I control the xaxis they way i want for instance keeping it between 0 and 1.

i.e.  `plot(x,y,xlim=c(0,1),ylim=c(0,6))`

Is this a bug? If it is and this cannot be solved is there another package that would have the same functionality?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The short answer is, you need to set the `asp` argument of the call to plot to `0` as the default is `asp = 1` which produces the behavior you see (i.e., it's not a bug, it's a feature). The long answer with explanation follows.

---

As you noticed correctly, `xaxis` varies according to `yaxis`. Specifically, the x-axis has approxamitely the same distance between high and low numbers as `yaxis`:

- If `yaxis = c(0,6)`, the x-axis goes from -3 to 4. `6 - 0 = 6` and `4 - (-3) = 7`
- If `yaxis = c(0,3)`, the x-axis goes from -1 to 2. `3 - 0 = 2 - (-1) = 3`

Igraph seems to keep a constant ratio between the axes.

If you call `?plot.igraph` (the plotting function called with an `igraph` object, can also be found via `help(package = "igraph")`), you find under `See Also`:

> `igraph.plotting` for the detailed description of the plotting
>   parameters

And if you click on this link (or call `?igraph.plotting`)and go through the parameters you will find:

> `asp` A numeric constant, it gives the asp parameter for plot, the aspect ratio. Supply 0 here if you don't want to give an aspect ratio.
>   It is ignored by tkplot and rglplot.
>
> Defaults to 1.

Hence the aspect parameter `asp` defaults to `1` in igraph. If you want another ratio, set it to `0`:

```
plot(g,layout=l,rescale=F,axes=TRUE,ylim=c(0,6),xlim=c(0,1), asp = 0)
```

This answers your question. However, note that the points are now rather big. You will probably want to play around with the following parameters (found on `?igraph.plotting` but note that many of the parameters need to be prefixed by `vertex.` as done by me):

- `vertex.size`  Default is 15, 5 seems better
- `vertex.label.cex` Default is 1, 0.8 seems better.

The following produces a nicer plot:

`plot(g,layout=l,rescale=F,axes=TRUE,ylim=c(0,6),xlim=c(0,1), asp = 0, vertex.size = 5, vertex.label.cex = 0.8)`

[image: nicer plot]