# How to resize RMarkdown page to fit a big plot (non-rescaled igraph)

Tags: r, r-markdown, igraph

I need to fit a big igraph plot in an RMarkdown document, but a lot of the nodes and labels overlap (in a way similar to the image below).

[image]

I figured using the 'rescale=FALSE' argument could work, but then the problem is that the plot size is bigger than the page size, regardless of the fig.height, fig.width options.

[image]

Below you can see a reproducible example (save as .Rmd and Knit):

````
---
output: pdf_document
---

# How to resize page to fit plot?
```{r pressure, echo=FALSE, fig.height=20, fig.width=20, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
library(igraph)
st <- make_star(500)
set.seed(100)
plot(st, vertex.size=10, vertex.label=NA, rescale=FALSE) 
```
````

There is a way to adjust the page size to a non-rescaled igraph?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can adjust the page size by adding the `classoption` in the `YAML`.

But you can also play around with the fig size and the `xlim()` and `ylim()` to adjust the figure inside the page as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32857024/increasing-the-distance-between-igraph-nodes).

````
---
output:
  pdf_document:
documentclass: article
classoption:
  - a1paper
---

# How to resize page to fit plot?
```{r pressure, echo=FALSE, fig.height=30, fig.width=40, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
library(igraph)
st <- make_star(500)
set.seed(100)
plot(st, vertex.size=10, ylim=c(3,5), xlim = c(-7, 15),vertex.label=NA, rescale=FALSE)
```
````

[image]

Comment: Awesome answer, very useful info when plotting decision trees with the igraph "layout_as_tree". You saved me a lot of source code digging